# Sax Stax Chunks Processing in Java

Tags: xml-parsing, out-of-memory, sax, stax, chunks

Stax and Sax parser character method mentioning it returns chunk of data in the documentation but i am receiving Out of memory, Can any one please explain this ? if possible an example, i am trying to read a Xml that will have large content between one xml tag.

`<x>......too long data...</x>`

looking at if i could override this or some properties i could set ?   i found we can set  CDATA_CHUNK_SIZE = "jdk.xml.cdataChunkSize" in Latest versions but that's not an option for me.

**In Stax parser** : "a processor may return all contiguous character data in a single chunk, or it may split it into several chunks."

**In SAX parser: characters method** "

characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)

Receive notification of character data.

The Parser will call this method to report each chunk of character data. SAX parsers may return all contiguous character data in a single chunk, or they may split it into several chunks; however, all of the characters in any single event must come from the same external entity so that the Locator provides useful information.
"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.XMLStringBuffer.append(XMLStringBuffer.java:208)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanData(XMLEntityScanner.java:1370)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanCDATASection(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1654)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3020)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:558)
    at com.javacodegeeks.StAXParserDemo.main(StAXParserDemo.java:65)
```

Comment: "SAX parsers may return all contiguous character data in a single chunk" - obviously if that happens it would run out of memory for a sufficiently large chunk.

Comment: Any property that i could set to restrict that ?

Comment: Not sure. The usual answer would be to choose a different parser, but maybe xerces has one. I don't know. I use woodstox, but I don't know which behaviour that has off the top of my head either.

Comment: Thanks, I have figured out Apache Xerces2 is doing it in chunks